# How can I redirect from one url to another using Tuckey URL rewriting without change url in browser?

Tags: java, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I've two 2 urls  e.g. www.1st-domain.com and www.2nd-domain.com I want to write a Tuckey URL Rewrite rule to redirect any request that goes to www.1st-domain.com to www.2nd-domain.com but url in browser should not be changed

I'm trying something like:

```
<rule>
    <from>www.1st-domain.com</from>
    <to type="redirect">www.2nd-domain.com</to>
</rule>
```

This is working fine, but URL is also change from www.1st-domain.com to www.2nd-domain.com. and when I removed type = redirect URL Redirect is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Please use type="forward" instead and it should work fine.
Let me know how it goes.